# Connection reset by peer while using apache as reverse proxy

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, apache2

I've installed Transmission daemon on machine #0(Ubuntu 16.04.5, native), and Apache2(Apache/2.4.18) on machine #1(Ubuntu 16.04.5, on XCP-NG 75). Apache is now reverse-proxying transmission for adopting TLS to transmission rpc.

Wherever I connect to transmission via apache, it continues returning 'Connection reset by Peer' for few minutes interval.

I can sure this is not a problem of network, since SSH connection from My PC to machine #1, and machine #1 to machine #0 both remains stablized.

This is a config for transmission vHost.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile [A Certificate File]
        SSLCertificateKeyFile [A Certificate Key File]
        SSLCertificateChainFile [A Certificate Chain File]
        ServerName [Hostname]

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPass / http://[Address to machine #0]:9091/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://[Address to machine #0]:9091/
        <Location "/">
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Transmission"
            AuthUserFile [Authentication File]
            Require valid-user
        </Location>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Which makes this kind of problem? and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've (finally) joined the StackExchange community to help you, as nobody has answered yet.
I was facing the same issue today, and it looked definitely related to the Apache SSL info we could notice within verbose logs :

> [ssl:info] [...] The timeout specified has expired: [...] SSL input filter read failed.

So a "solution" (mostly a "workaround" IMHO) is proposed [here](http://wiki.indie-it.com/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server#HOWTO:_Fix_Error:_The_timeout_specified_has_expired:_SSL_input_filter_read_failed).

Here is a blog post I've written about this very setup : [link](https://samuel.forestier.app/blog/security/how-to-secure-transmission-behind-apache-as-tls-reverse-proxy).

Bye

PS : In my specific case, `SetEnv nokeepalive` sufficed.

---

**TL;DR**

Try adding `SetEnv nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown` to your VHOST configuration.

Comment: Use of links in answers to cite sources is welcome. But it is no substitute for writing an answer that can be used on its own without the links. Please edit your answer to include all the necessary information. Also greetings don't belong in questions and answers on this site, only include information relevant to the question/answer.